# iOS and bluetooth...what framework will i need?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy board. I want to develop a iOS app for the iPhone 4S that receives and sends data from the board.

What framework do I need to reseach/find-documentation-for? Will the Core Bluetooth framework in the iOS SDK work? Will I need to use the GameKit framework?

I just started looking into iOS development a few days ago so I'm trying to navigate through this maze! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

[Core Bluetooth which is part of the iOS5 SDK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) is all that you need.

You do not need Gamekit or MFi to develop Bluetooth low energy apps.

You will also need a device that supports Bluetooth Low Energy 4.0 (iPhone 4S or the new iPad) to test your app.

Comment: Are you sure? The previous comment says that you need to sign up for the MFi program and that there is a authentication chip involved.

Comment: Yes - Pretty sure - As the previous comment said the Auth chip is needed only if you need to access the Apple protocols - If you are developing an app to talk with your device there is no need to have MFi.

Comment: To connect to a BT 4.0 device (BLE) you need iOS 5. This is the correct answer, the one currently marked as answer is incorrect.

Comment: Dennis, sorry for sending this on such an old post but finding a place where a person can get BLE help is hard!!!  Anyway, quick question, if I have a iPhone 4s and an iPad 3, both BLE devices, can I write an app that allows communication between the two?  I assume, yes, but in my sample they do not find each other, they search forever... can you lend any advice?

Comment: May be this should be a new Question it will help others also who would search for this .. The answer is No. Pls post this as a new question and message me the link I will try to explain iin detail

Answer (score 7):

**Frameworks which are used for discovering the device via Bluetooth are:**

CoreBluetooth framework for discovering BLE devices

GameKit Framework for discovering other type of devices.

EAaccessory framework which can be used to interact with paired Bluetooth devices or devices connected through wired, Apple Connector at the base of the device.

Apple MFi Program  means you will have a device that is designed to be compatible with iOS devices (meaning, the manufacturer must be a member of the Apple MFi program) and the device manufacturer most provide a protocol that you must add to your applications info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on Core Blutooth.  Gamekit will only be useful with other iOS devices.